# Почему возникает ошибка Unrecognized datatype for attribute "users.name"?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

для подключения к бд постгрес использую Sequelize
вот такая таблица

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
       id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
       name varchar(510) NOT NULL,
       family varchar(510) NOT NULL,
       second_name varchar(510) NOT NULL
);
create sequence user_id_seq start with 1 increment by 1;
ALTER SEQUENCE user_id_seq OWNED BY users.id;
```

вот   user.js

```
const Config = require('../config');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(Config.db.name, Config.db.username, Config.db.password, {
    host: Config.db.host,
    dialect: 'postgres'
});
sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database 1:', err);
    });
const User = sequelize.define("users", {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    name: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    family: {
        type: sequelize.STRING
    },
    second_name: {
        type: sequelize.STRING
    }
});
sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(result=>{
    console.log(result);
})
    .catch(err=> console.log(err));
```

получаю вот такую ошибку

> Connection has been established successfully. ...
>
> Object. (/var/www/nodeShop.lc/model/user.js:17:24) ...
>
> Error: Unrecognized datatype for attribute "users.name"
>
> rawAttributes._.mapValues(/var/www/nodeShop.lc/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1005:15)
>
> /var/www/nodeShop.lc/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13401:38
>
> /var/www/nodeShop.lc/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4905:15
>
> baseForOwn (/var/www/nodeShop.lc/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
>
> Function.mapValues(/var/www/nodeShop.lc/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13400:7)
>
> Function.init(/var/www/nodeShop.lc/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1001:28)
>
> Sequelize.define(/var/www/nodeShop.lc/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:426:11)
>
> Object. (/var/www/nodeShop.lc/model/user.js:17:24)
>
> ...

подскажите пожалуйста почему ?

Comment: Меня смущает, что у вас sequelize то с большой буквы, то с маленькой

Comment: поменял у id Sequelize.INTEGER на  sequelize.INTEGER  получил ошибку

Comment: Error: Unrecognized datatype for attribute "users.id"

Comment: Что это за программирование наугад?

Comment: просто менял написание  sequelize с большой на маленькую букву не увидел опечатку. И потом почему програмирование я учусь работать на node

Comment: Потому что нормальное программирование подразумевает чтение документации. Я вот открыл документацию https://sequelize.org/master/ и там на первом же примере кода `Sequelize.STRING` с большой буквы.

Comment: @Sergalas напишите в строке const User = sequelize.define('"users"', { ...далее как было...

Comment: @Sergalas и для типов используйте Sequelize (с большой буквы) везде